# How to add values to the Array Java

Tags: java, arrays

need your help guys.How can i add some values to array in WHILE loop.I prepare some script which find two columns from the text file,i want to put this data into 2 separate array while executing the loop.

```
while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
    linecount++;
    int indexfound = line.indexOf(dcp);

    if (indexfound > -1) {
        //place your code here
        System.out.println(line.substring(6,10) + " " + line.substring(15,19).trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: Which array are you referring to?

Comment: Java's an object-oriented language.  Create a meaningful abstraction that combines two values rather than two arrays.  Load those objects into a List.

Comment: Arrays are created above in my script,i just place some part of it where i have to add values to this arrays and then play with them in other place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using an `ArrayList` because it's generally easier to change length.

```
//create the two lists before loop starts.
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

while (( line = bf.readLine()) != null)
{
    linecount++;
    int indexfound = line.indexOf(dcp);

    if (indexfound > -1) {
        //place your code here

        //add the two elements to their respective list
        list1.add(line.substring(6,10));
        list2.add(line.substring(15,19).trim());

        System.out.println(line.substring(6,10) + " " + line.substring(15,19).trim());
    }
}
```

Then later you can loop as so:

```
//NOTE:  list1 and list 2 should have the same size!
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list1.get(i) + " " + list2.get(i));
}
```